# typescript es-lint error: react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I first thought it's a false positive, but until now I have no clue why the error is a helpful thing.

How to make sense `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` error when your external props function is used in `useEffect` doesn't need to be put in dependency?

```
interface props {
  someExternalPropFunction: any;
}

const App: React.FC<props> = ({ someExternalPropFunction }) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState<initialStateProps>({
    eventInfo: {
      name: "",
      location: ""
    }
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    someExternalPropFunction(formValues);
  }, [formValues]); //what is going on here?

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-swirles-cu0qw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dep list needs `someExternalPropFunction` since the prop might change.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    someExternalPropFunction(formValues);
  }, [someExternalPropFunction, formValues]); // now it is fixed
```

[codesandbox, fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cartwright-ctw0q)

Comment: why someExternalPropFunction might change? it's a function

Comment: from a component lifecycle point-of-view, any prop can potentially change, even if you the developer don't intend on it changing